# How to return a list of Name/Value pairs from a Linq to SQL query?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for a way to return a name value pair list directly from a Linq to SQL query without having to loop through the results like I'm doing in the code below:

```
Public Shared Function GetUserTransactionCounts(fromDate As DateTime, toDate As DateTime) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
    Using dc As New ProntoDataContext()
        Dim users As IEnumerable(Of User) = From u In dc.Users Where u.CreatedTransactions.Any(Function(t) t.TSCreate >= fromDate And t.TSCreate <= toDate)

        Dim list As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
        For Each user As User In users
            Dim item As New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(user.CommonName, user.CreatedTransactions.Count)
            list.Add(item)
        Next
        Return list
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to `IEnumerable`, and then using `Select`:

```
Dim users As IEnumerable(Of User) = From u In dc.Users Where u.CreatedTransactions.Any(Function(t) t.TSCreate >= fromDate And t.TSCreate <= toDate)
Dim list As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = users.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(x.CommonName, x.CreatedTransactions.Count)).ToList()
```

**EDIT :** If you would like to make an `IEnumerable`, remove the `ToList`:

```
Dim enumerable As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) = users.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(x.CommonName, x.CreatedTransactions.Count))
```

This will not run the query until the `enumerable` is enumerated for the first time.

Comment: I am not very good with VB.NET syntax, having to translate from C#. I think this should work, but if it does not, please let me know, and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Sorry, C# would have been fine - I read both.  Am I correct in saying that the actual SQL statement wouldn't fire until the "list" object from the second line was used in some way?  Meaning that, there isn't a second trip to the db using this method, correct?

Comment: @EdenMachine Actually, you just pointed out an error in my answer: I am assigning an `IEnumerable` to a `List`. I was planning to add a `ToList()` at the end of the query, but I forgot; I did it now. I also added an example with `IEnumerable`, the one that will not go to the DB until you enumerate the elements for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx#Y900)

May look like this

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Interger) = users .ToDictionary(Function(u) u.CommonName,Function(u) u.CreatedTransactions.Count )
```